# How to dynamically change the InfoAfterFile in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I have an InnoSetup project, i want to have the ability to set the InfoAfterFile according to the command line parameters sent to the setup exe.
is there a way to do so? is there something like the "Check" paramter that will work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a value for the [`InfoAfterFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_infoafterfile) directive at runtime. Its value specifies the file which is compiled into the output setup and so this directive value must be known at compilation time. However, you can load a file manually into the `InfoAfterMemo` control. The following example shows how to load a file specified by the command line parameter `-iaf` only if that parameter is present and the file exists:

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
InfoAfterFile=c:\DefaultFileToBeDisplayed.txt

[Code]
const
  InfoAfterFileParam = '-iaf';

function TryGetInfoAfterFileParam(var FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  // initialize result
  Result := False;
  // iterate all the command line parameters
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    // store the current parameter to the local variable
    S := ParamStr(I);
    // try to find the position of the substring specified by the
    // InfoAfterFileParam constant; in this example we're looking
    // for the "-iaf" string in the current parameter
    Index := Pos(InfoAfterFileParam, S);
    // if the InfoAfterFileParam constant string was found in the
    // current parameter, then...
    if Index = 1 then
    begin
      // strip out the InfoAfterFileParam constant string from the
      // parameter string, so we get only file name
      Delete(S, Index, Length(InfoAfterFileParam));
      // now trim the spaces from rest of the string, which is the
      // file name
      S := Trim(S);
      // check if the file pointed by the file name we got exists;
      // if so, then return True for this function call and assign
      // the output file name to the output parameter
      if FileExists(S) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        FileName := S;
      end;
      // we've found the parameter starting with InfoAfterFileParam
      // constant string, so let's exit the function
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  // when the parameter was found and the file to be loaded exists,
  // then load it to the InfoAfterMemo control
  if TryGetInfoAfterFileParam(FileName) then
    WizardForm.InfoAfterMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
end;
```

Please note, that you will have to specify the [`InfoAfterFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_infoafterfile) directive, otherwise the page won't be even shown. Also note, that I'm looking for the command line parameter starting with `-iaf`, so you'd need to modify this code in real if you expect to use e.g. `-iafx` parameter. Here is the sample call of such setup from command line:

```
Setup.exe -iaf"C:\SomeFolder\SomeFileToBeShownAsInfoAfter.txt"
```

Comment: If you change the syntax to `/iaf="filename"` then you can dramatically simplify the above code to `ExpandConstant('{param:iaf}')`...  (which would make it easier for the OP to see the bit that really matters for them)